# Applying CSS file to JavaFX WebView

Tags: css, webview, javafx

I am trying to apply a CSS file to a JavaFX WebView object.  From what I've read, this should do the trick, but evidently I'm missing something because the WebView displays without any styling.

```
package net.snortum.play;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebviewCssPlay extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("CSS Styling Test");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(200);

        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        webEngine.loadContent("<html><body><h1>Hello!</h1>This is a <b>test</b></body></html>");

        VBox root = new VBox(); 
        root.getChildren().addAll(browser);
        root.getStyleClass().add("browser");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/net/snortum/play/web_view.css");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My CSS file looks like this:

```
.browser {
    -fx-background-color: #00ff80;
    -fx-font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the style of the `WebView`, or of the HTML page displayed in the `WebView`?

Comment: The HTML in the WebView.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[James_D already explained in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785852/2991525) how to convert "JavaFx CSS" to "HTML CSS", but it may be more convenient to use [`WebEngine.setUserStylesheetLocation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#setUserStyleSheetLocation-java.lang.String-) to set a stylesheet that contains the CSS:

```
webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("style.css").toString());
```

*style.css* contains the css code:

```css
body {
    background-color: #00ff80; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Your code applies CSS to the JavaFX `WebView` node; you are trying to apply CSS to the HTML document displayed inside the `WebView`. Since the web view has no JavaFX nodes with any text, `-fx-font-family` has no effect, and the background of the HTML page will obscure the background of the WebView, so `-fx-background-color` will not be visible.

In order to do what you want, you need to manipulate the DOM of the loaded document and apply (standard, HTML-applicable) CSS to it. This would look something like:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class WebViewCssPlay extends Application {

    private static final String CSS = 
              "body {"
            + "    background-color: #00ff80; "
            + "    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;"
            + "}";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("CSS Styling Test");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(200);

        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                Document doc = webEngine.getDocument() ;
                Element styleNode = doc.createElement("style");
                Text styleContent = doc.createTextNode(CSS);
                styleNode.appendChild(styleContent);
                doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(styleNode);

                System.out.println(webEngine.executeScript("document.documentElement.innerHTML"));
            }
        });
        webEngine.loadContent("<html><body><h1>Hello!</h1>This is a <b>test</b></body></html>");

        VBox root = new VBox(); 
        root.getChildren().addAll(browser);
        root.getStyleClass().add("browser");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
//        scene.getStylesheets().add("/net/snortum/play/web_view.css");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Edit: also see @fabian's answer, which is much cleaner and preferable in the vast majority of use cases.